# MySQL procedure, use SELECT to UPDATE comparison

Tags: mysql, sql-update, procedure, sql

In MySQL, I need to move past the current day to the last position on the last date by adding +1 registered.

Table:

```
Id |  Date
4    2012-03-04
5    2012-03-05
6    2012-03-06
7    2012-03-07
```

Today is 2012-03-06 OK? So I need procedure result:

```
Id |  Date
4    2012-03-09
5    2012-03-08
6    2012-03-06
7    2012-03-07
```

Comment: Tks zerkms i found another solution with 2 querys.

Answer (score 0):

Probably. You want to add one day to each date.

Try this:

```
Select id,date_add(datefield,interval 1 day) as date from tablename
```

Comment: Your query add 1 day for all days, i don´t need this, i need get the last day (2012-03-04 and 2012-03-05) and add day´s based on the last day (2012-03-07)

Comment: I found another solution, 2 querys, tks